# Cocos2d: UIImageView will not remove itself from glView

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, uiimageview

In my application I am pushing a new scene that has 2 UIImageViews on it. 
In the init method of the new scene, the UIImageViews are allocated and then added
to the view using:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview: _someUIImageView];
```

In the dealloc method, I am removing the layer as a delegate for the touchDispatcher and also removing the UIImageviews like:

```
[_someUIImageView removeFromSuperview]; _someUIImageView = nil;
```

However when I pop the scene, I do return to the scene that I want, but I am still able to interact with the UIImageviews from the scene before. I have tried replacing the scene instead of just popping it, but still they are there. I am using Cocos2d 2.0 if that makes any difference.

Thanks

Comment: did you check if dealloc is called?

Answer (score 1):

@Kreiri is alright, maybe the dealloc method is not called when you remove de scene,

review the retains objects, maybe someone is not released and that cause the dealloc method is not called.

Comment: It is true that the dealloc method was not being called. I was using ARC, and despite using instruments, I could't find where I was going wrong. Finally adding the -(void)onExit seemed to work. Thanks :)